# Binary Search of String within a linked list

Tags: java, search, binary

I need to perform a binary search on a linked list with various data types. The code below will not compile. I can't seem to get the compareTo() to work.

Here is the linked list class:

```
public class Contributor {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String country;
private String phone;
private double contribution;
private int id;}
```

The binary search method is below. The search needs to find a certain lastName using the binary search method.

```
 public void binarySearch(List<Contributor> l, String key) {
    System.out.println("Binary search.");

    int upperBound = l.size();
    int lowerBound = 1;
    int midpoint = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
    int difference = upperBound - lowerBound;

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        if (key.compareTo(l.get(midpoint - 1))&& difference != 1) {
            upperBound = midpoint - 1;
            midpoint = upperBound / 2;
        } else if (key.compareTo(l.get(midpoint - 1)) && difference != 1) {
            lowerBound = midpoint + 1;
            midpoint = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

        } else if (key.equals(l.get(midpoint - 1))) {
            midpoint = midpoint - 1;

            System.out.println("We found " + key + " at position " + midpoint + " in the list.");
            i = l.size();
        } else {
            System.out.println("We couldn't find " + key + " in the list.");
            i = l.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this will be deeply inefficient -- O(n log n), not O(log n).  This is because linked lists are, almost by definition, deeply inefficient.

Comment: What is your question? or problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a logic error here - as Akshay says, your key is a `String`, so it doesn't make sense to search for it in a list of `Contibutor`s - you would need to search for a `Contributor`.

More than this though, a precondition for binary search is that the list is sorted, which requires that your `Contributor` object be `Comparable` (or at least that you supply a `Comparator`.

I've modified your code to fix these problems:

```
class Contributor implements Comparable<Contributor>{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country;
    private String phone;
    private double contribution;
    private int id;

    public int compareTo(Contributor o) {
        return Integer.valueOf(id).compareTo(o.id);
    }
}

public class BinarySearch {
    /**
     * Performs a binary search for <code>key</code> in the list <code>l</code>.
     * 
     * @param l Ordered list of Contributors.
     * @param key Value to search for.
     */
    public void binarySearch(List<Contributor> l, Contributor key) {
        System.out.println("Binary search.");

        int upperBound = l.size();
        int lowerBound = 1;
        int midpoint = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
        int difference = upperBound - lowerBound;

        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            if (key.compareTo(l.get(midpoint - 1)) <0 ) {
                upperBound = midpoint - 1;
                midpoint = upperBound / 2;
            } else if (key.compareTo(l.get(midpoint - 1))>0 ) {
                lowerBound = midpoint + 1;
                midpoint = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

            } else if (key.equals(l.get(midpoint - 1))) {
                midpoint = midpoint - 1;

                System.out.println("We found " + key + " at position "
                        + midpoint + " in the list.");
                i = l.size();
            } else {
                System.out.println("We couldn't find " + key + " in the list.");
                i = l.size();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should fix your compilation error, although as others note, the search logic itself has some bugs.  Please note too that a precondition of the`binarySearch` method is that the list be ordered, and this requirement should be documented.  I've added a javadoc comment to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at your code l.get(midpoint-1) returns Contributor object not a String, and key.compareTo method can only take an argument of type String.

Answer (score 0):

compareTo() function returns integer value. so try

```
if(key.compareTo(str) < 0)
```

or

```
if(key.compareTo(str) > 0)
```

or

```
if(key.compareTo(str) == 0)
```

Also compare it with the String from the Contributor class, not with the class itself. that is

```
if(key.compareTo((l.get(midpoint - 1)).firstName)<0)
```

another logical mistake is when you do

```
midpoint = upperBound / 2;
```

you are assuming `lowerbound` to be **1**. But its value may change in iterations. So consider that as well